# Post checked checkbox value, get in nodejs and save in MongoDB

Tags: html, node.js

Here's my HTML script:

```
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="color" value="red">red
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name='color' value="blue">blue
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name='color' value="Green">green
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name='color' value="black">black
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="benz">Benz
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="BMW">BMW
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="Kia">Kia
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="Mazzerati">Mazzerati
            <br>
        </div>
        <input type="button" onclick="sendOPT()" value="send">
    </form>
    <div id="show"></div>
</body>
<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendOPT() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/send',
            method: 'post'
        }).done(message => {
            $(show).html("its Done");
        })
    }
</script>
```

I want to send checked checkBox item into my backend (nodejs) and save them into my database(Mongodb)

I wrote my backend side as the following:

```
app.post('/send', async(req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log("start");
        const body = _.pick(req.body, ['colors', 'cars'])
        console.log(body);

        let test = new fav({
            favcolor: body.colors,
            favcar: body.cars
        })
        await test.save();
        console.log(test);
        res.send('ok')


    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).json({
            ERROR: `Something wend wrong and err is ${e}.`
        })
    }
});
```

When I check and click for send, I have nothing, I have tested my database and backend by any input like as radio or text and it working good, but in this situation, not working.

[**NOTE**]:

- I use (express,Mongoose,body-parse,lodash,...)

Answer (score 0):

There are few changes required in HTML page

1. Add action to form
2. change button type to submit
3. first checkbox name is changed to "colors" as per node.js code

   ```
   <form method="POST" action="send">
   <div>
       <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red">red
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" name='colors' value="blue">blue
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" name='colors' value="Green">green
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" name='colors' value="black">black
       <br>
   </div>
   <br>
   <br>
   <div>
       <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="benz">Benz
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="BMW">BMW
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="Kia">Kia
       <br>
       <input type="checkbox" name='cars' value="Mazzerati">Mazzerati
       <br>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="send">
   ```

   Above code is sending POST form data that I observed on network tab. Please check end to end with your backend code.

OR

You can use jquery AJAX as well but you forgot to add "data" attribute. Note: form data will not be automatically added to ajax call.